# Cannot get proxy_next_upstream to work

Tags: nginx, load-balancing

I have an nginx load balancer with three nodes, one of which is the actual load balancer, my config is bellow.

```
upstream backend  {
  least_conn;
  server 127.0.0.1:8090 max_fails=3 fail_timeout=30s;
  server dummy_ip_1:8090 max_fails=3 fail_timeout=30s;
  server dummy_ip_2:8090 max_fails=3 fail_timeout=30s;
  keepalive 32;
}

server {
  location / {
    proxy_pass  http://backend;
    proxy_next_upstream error timeout invalid_header http_500 http_502 http_503 http_504 http_403 http_404 http_429;
  }
}
```

Now, whenever I try a request that gives a 404 or a 503 error code the request is only tried by the node that first received it, without being passed to the second or third node. Am I missing something here, isn't this what proxy_next_upstream should do?

Comment: How did you check? Show logs

Comment: This is the request `curl -d "text=Worthington ist ein US-amerikanischer Vorort der Stadt Columbus in Franklin County, Ohio. erhob sie 1984 zur Basilica minor. Shoes 4 wird komplett neu geschrieben."  -X POST http://test_server/category1` and I am watching the access logs on all my 3 servers like this: `tail -f /var/log/nginx/access.log |grep curl` and only one server processes the requests

Comment: test_server is just a dummy name that I use

Comment: See nginx.org/r/proxy_next_upstream, in particular the `non_idempotent` option I'm guessing.